# onActivityResult intent data returns null in kitkat but works in lollipop and marshmallow for UPI based payments with BHIM App

Tags: android, upi

Response is available through data intent for Lollipop and marshmallow but not for kitkat. The response codes are available when working with marshmallow but data intent returns null for kitkat.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if(data!=null){
    //get the parameters available from data

        String scheme = data.getScheme(); 
        String host = data.getHost(); 
        List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
        String payeevpa = params.get(0); 
        String payeename = params.get(1); 
        String payeeamount = params.get(2); 
        String payeeref = params.get(3); 

        String UPI;
  //UPI Link creation     
        UPI = "upi://pay?pa="+payeevpa+"&pn="+payeename+"&tr="+payeeref+"&am="+payeeamount;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(UPI));
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
      //starting activity for result
        startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
    }
    else {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseLanguage.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
    }
}
```

onActivityResult is called for kitkat but the intent data is null

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 //   Log.d("requestcode",requestCode+"");
 //   Log.d("resultcode",resultCode+"");
   String abc=null;
    if(data!=null){
     //intent data is available here for marshmallow
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            Object value = bundle.get(key);
        //    Log.d("VAL", String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,
                    value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
            abc=value.toString();


        }
   }
    else{
      //intent data is null for kitkat
        Toast.makeText(this,"Data is Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. What this is about? And what kind of intent you used?

Comment: user clicks on a web link, it opens my app then with the parameters it opens another app, the response from the another app is available on onActivityResult but the data intent is null only for kitkat version